# Number of combinations in sign matrices with sign non-congruent rows and vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

Given an $N \times N$ sign matrix $\mathbf{S}$ with $s_{ij} = \pm 1$ for all $1 \leq i, j \leq N$. There are $2^{N \cdot N}$ different such matrices. Now, if we add the constraint that all the rows should be sign non-congruent, i.e., for every pair $i$ and $j$:
$$
\exists k:  s_{jk} s_{ik} = -1 \wedge \exists l:  s_{jl} s_{il} = +1.  
$$
The same should hold also for all the columnes:
$$
\exists k:  s_{kj} s_{ki} = -1 \wedge \exists l:  s_{lj} s_{li} = +1.  
$$
How many such matrices $\mathbf{S}$ exist?

From the comments:

> If we only consider the rows: the first rows can be chosen arbitrarily. Then second row two options less (the same and the opposite). The third row has four options less (against the earlier two rows). And so on.

Comment: @Shaun If we only consider the rows: the first rows can be chosen arbitrarily. Then second row two options less (the same and the opposite). The third row has four options less (against the earlier two rows). And so on.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A088310

Comment: If you only consider rows, the count would be
$$\binom{2^n}{n}n!$$
Reasoning: Choose $n$ distinct rows from $2n$ possible rows, and then permute them arbitrarily.

Comment: @quasi Thank you very much for the OEIS reference. I think this helps me to solve the combination of columns and rows counting.